# Is it possible to clone a request to use it later?

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to clone the `flask.request` object to use it later?  I want to send the cloned request to another thread to repeat the same job.  How can I put the cloned object on top of the request stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as simple as copying environ object. It has a copy() method that does the trick:

```
environ = flask.request.environ.copy()
```

Now you can use app.request_context to push a new context (with the cloned environ) to the flask context stack:

```
with app.request_context(environ):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the object to a thread while processing the request, I think it may be easier (and preferable) to pass the actual request object rather than the flask.request [proxy object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#notes-on-proxies).

```
request._get_current_object()
```

The object returned from this call can be accessed across threads.